# Java serialization over network

Tags: java, serialization, network-programming

Just want to know if there's a tutorial or a how-to for serializing objects, putting them into a stream over network, and deserialize it on the other side. I understand the principles of serialization, I/O, streams, sockets, and so on, I just would like an example of a client sending an object to a server to start with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~adenau/teaching/cs303/lecture12.pdf) (pdf) is a useful tutorial which walks you through the basics of serialisation, and sockets, then ties the two concepts together (about halfway through the slides) to show how to serialise an object and send it from client to server (no RMI). I think that's precisely what you want.

Comment: Really show how to use serialization AND sockets, thank you !

Answer (score 7):

Its pretty simple, actually.  Just make your objects serializable, and create an ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream that are connected to whatever underlying stream you have, say FileInputStream, etc.  Then just write() whatever object you want to the stream and read it on the other side.

Heres an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/ReadingBasicDataFromanObjectStream.htm) for you.

Comment: You might want to be a little more careful about closing your resources than that example.

Answer (score 5):

Java provides (binary) object serialization using the [ObjectOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) (and [ObjectInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)). You can just writeObject() into the stream and readObject() on the other end.
All you need to do for this to work is implement the Serializable interface.

But rather than doing that manually, you may be interested in taken it one level up and using [Remote Method Invocation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/index.html). With RMI you can call methods on objects that live in another JVM, and all the serialization and networking happens under the hood.

And for the sake of completeness, there is also [XML bean serialization](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence4/), if you cannot use the binary format. That XML format is very generic (read: verbose and ugly), but there are some popular libraries (like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)) that create alternative XML serializations.

Comment: XStream also offers JSON serialization (with Jettison) which can be very useful in cross-language projects: www.json.org

Comment: Never heard about RMI, seems like WCF in Microsoft technology, hope I'm not wrong...  Thank you for the idea !

Comment: @elbaid More like RPC

Answer (score 3):

you can create object streams using the java api and send any serializable object. but youll have to mind that these go unencrypted through the network:

on the sender's side:

```
CustomObject objectToSend=new CustomObject();
Socket s = new Socket("yourhostname", 1234);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(objectToSend);
out.flush();
```

and on the receiving end:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket s = server.accept();
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
CustomObject objectReceived = (CustomObject) in.readObject();
```

Comment: I wonder how many people use native serialization instead of other transport/encoding libraries. So far, I know that they only issue to look out for is security but that can be taken care of with SSL. I'd still like to know the speed difference though and I'd imagine native serialization to be afoot