# Server and Client using Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

Are there any examples of a server and a client that use sockets, but that have send and get methods?  I'm doing this networked battleship program, almost finished, but can't get the server and clients to work.  I have made a chat program that only sends strings, but this time I need to send objects.  I'm already frustrated, so is there any source code that already has this.

Here's the code for the client... how would you modify it to allow to send objects?  Also I need to be listening for incoming objects and process them right away.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleChat extends JFrame {
  private Socket         communicationSocket   = null;
  private PrintWriter    outStream             = null;
  private BufferedReader inStream              = null;
  private Boolean        communicationContinue = true;
  private String         disconnectString      = "disconnect764*#$1";
  private JMenuItem      disconnectItem;
  private JTextField     displayLabel;
  private final Color    colorValues[]         = { Color.black, Color.blue, Color.red, Color.green };

  // set up GUI
  public SimpleChat() {
    super("Simple Chat");

    // set up File menu and its menu items
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    fileMenu.setMnemonic('F');

    // set up Activate Server menu item
    JMenuItem serverItem = new JMenuItem("Activate Server");
    serverItem.setMnemonic('S');
    fileMenu.add(serverItem);
    serverItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // anonymous inner class
                // display message dialog when user selects About...
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                  setUpServer();
                }
              } // end anonymous inner class
              ); // end call to addActionListener

    // set up Activate Client menu item
    JMenuItem clientItem = new JMenuItem("Activate Client");
    clientItem.setMnemonic('C');
    fileMenu.add(clientItem);
    clientItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // anonymous inner class
                // display message dialog when user selects About...
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                  setUpClient();
                }
              } // end anonymous inner class
              ); // end call to addActionListener

    // set up Activate Client menu item
    disconnectItem = new JMenuItem("Disconnect Client/Server");
    disconnectItem.setMnemonic('D');
    disconnectItem.setEnabled(false);
    fileMenu.add(disconnectItem);
    disconnectItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // anonymous inner
                    // class
                    // display message dialog when user selects About...
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                      disconnectClientServer(true);
                    }
                  } // end anonymous inner class
                  ); // end call to addActionListener

    // set up About... menu item
    JMenuItem aboutItem = new JMenuItem("About...");
    aboutItem.setMnemonic('A');
    fileMenu.add(aboutItem);
    aboutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // anonymous inner class
               // display message dialog when user selects About...
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SimpleChat.this, "This is an example\nof using menus", "About",
                                               JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
               }
             } // end anonymous inner class
             ); // end call to addActionListener

    // set up Exit menu item
    JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    exitItem.setMnemonic('x');
    fileMenu.add(exitItem);
    exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // anonymous inner class
              // terminate application when user clicks exitItem
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                disconnectClientServer(true);
                System.exit(0);
              }
            } // end anonymous inner class
            ); // end call to addActionListener

    // create menu bar and attach it to MenuTest window
    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(bar);
    bar.add(fileMenu);

    // set up label to display text
    displayLabel = new JTextField("Sample Text", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    displayLabel.setForeground(colorValues[0]);
    displayLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 72));
    displayLabel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // anonymous inner
                  // class
                  // display message dialog when user selects About...
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    sendData();
                  }
                } // end anonymous inner class
                ); // end call to addActionListener

    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    getContentPane().add(displayLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setSize(500, 200);
    setVisible(true);

  } // end constructor

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final SimpleChat application = new SimpleChat();
    application.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        application.disconnectClientServer(true);
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    // application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
  }

  public void setCommunicationSocket(Socket sock) {
    communicationSocket = sock;
    communicationContinue = true;
    disconnectItem.setEnabled(true);
  }

  public void setOutStream(PrintWriter out) {
    outStream = out;
  }

  public void setInStream(BufferedReader in) {
    inStream = in;
  }

  public void setUpServer() {
    ServerThread st = new ServerThread(this);
    st.start();
  }

  public void setUpClient() {
    ClientThread st = new ClientThread(this);
    st.start();
  }

  public void disconnectClientServer(Boolean sendMessage) {
    if (communicationSocket == null)
      return;

    try {
      // shut down socket read loop
      communicationContinue = false;
      disconnectItem.setEnabled(false);

      // send notification to other end of socket
      if (sendMessage == true)
        outStream.println(disconnectString);

      // sleep to let read loop shut down
      Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
      try {
        t.sleep(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        return;
      }

      outStream.close();
      inStream.close();
      communicationSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Stream Read Failed.");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SimpleChat.this, "Disconnection Failed", "SimpleChat", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      return;
    } finally {
      communicationSocket = null;
    }
  }

  public void sendData() {
    if (communicationSocket != null) {
      String data = displayLabel.getText();
      outStream.println(data);
    }
  }

  public void getData() {
    String inputLine;
    try {
      while (communicationContinue == true) {
        communicationSocket.setSoTimeout(100);
        // System.out.println ("Waiting for Connection");
        try {
          while (((inputLine = inStream.readLine()) != null)) {
            System.out.println("From socket: " + inputLine);
            if (inputLine.equals(disconnectString)) {
              disconnectClientServer(false);
              return;
            }
            displayLabel.setText(inputLine);
          }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
          // System.out.println ("Timeout Occurred");
        }
      } // end of while loop
      System.out.println("communication is false");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Stream Read Failed.");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SimpleChat.this, "Input Stream read failed", "SimpleChat",
                                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      return;
    }
  }
}

class ServerThread extends Thread {
  private SimpleChat sc;
  private JTextField display;

  public ServerThread(SimpleChat scParam) {
    sc = scParam;
  }

  public void run() {
    ServerSocket connectionSocket = null;

    try {
      connectionSocket = new ServerSocket(10007);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 10007.");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sc, "Could not listen on port: 10007", "Server", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      return;
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sc, "Server Socket is now activated", "Server", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    Socket communicationSocket = null;

    try {
      communicationSocket = connectionSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Accept failed.");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sc, "Accept failed", "Server", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      return;
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sc, "Comminucation is now activated", "Server", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    try {
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(communicationSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(communicationSocket.getInputStream()));

      sc.setCommunicationSocket(communicationSocket);
      sc.setOutStream(out);
      sc.setInStream(in);

      connectionSocket.close();

      sc.getData();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Accept failed.");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sc, "Creation of Input//Output Streams failed", "Server", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      return;
    }
  }
}

class ClientThread extends Thread {
  private SimpleChat sc;

  public ClientThread(SimpleChat scParam) {
    sc = scParam;
  }

  public void run() {
    Socket echoSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";

    try {
      echoSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, 10007);
      out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + ipAddress);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sc, "Don't know about host: " + ipAddress, "Client", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + "the connection to: " + ipAddress);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sc, "Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + ipAddress, "Client",
                                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      return;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sc, "Comminucation is now activated", "Client", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    sc.setCommunicationSocket(echoSocket);
    sc.setOutStream(out);
    sc.setInStream(in);

    sc.getData();
  }
}
```

Comment: this would be a lot clearer if without all of the extra code

Comment: See [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707987/java-serialization-over-network/708717#708717) for a reference to a tutorial that links together object serialization and subsequent send/getting via sockets without using RMI.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you read up on java serialization. There is an example [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).  Basically, there is built in serialization support.  Your class needs to implement **Serializable**.  Then you use **ObjectOutputStream** and **ObjectInputStream** to write object.

Answer (score 1):

You would be well advised to use libraries that shield you from the error prone low level socket programming.

For C++ look to Boost (http://www.boost.com) or ACE (http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html)

For Java I only found a document that talks about the acceptor pattern http://www.hillside.net/plop/plop99/proceedings/Fernandez3/RACPattern.PDF
But I am sure there's an implementation out somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right track. A chat program is a good place to start learning about sockets.

What you want is to use the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream classes.  You simply have to wrap your input stream / output stream with these filters.  ObjectOutputStream has a method writeObject(), and the ObjectInputStream has a corresponding readObject() method.

Most serialization examples show reading and writing objects to a file, but the same can be done using a socket stream.   See http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds4-2/serial.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't bother to read through your piles and piles of code, but in general you can't directly send objects over the network. Network communication is just bits and bytes. If you want to send objects, you'll need to serialize them on the sending side, and de-serialize them on the receiving side. There are tons of methods of serializing, eg JSON, XML, or even Java's built-in serialization support (only recommended if both the client and server will always be Java).

Answer (score 0):

You may find this code to be a decent starting point for making your own class.  These are two classes I made to somewhat abstract the work needed for TCP and UDP socket protocols:

http://code.google.com/p/hivewars/source/browse/trunk/SocketData.java
http://code.google.com/p/hivewars/source/browse/trunk/UDPSocket.java

Quick dislaimer: These are kind of versions of a feature full class, I just added functionality as I needed it.  However, it could help you start.