# Object Serialization Process?

Tags: serialization

Object serialization is the process of saving an object's state to a sequence of bytes. Does it saves only the instance variable or also the
object methods(like getter and setter methods) ? 
Once we we write the object to outputstream or some text file, how does it get transmitted over network?
Do we write the java object state in a text file. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java, when you serialize a object, the class code itself is not serialized. Instead, the output has a meta-data with your object class name(or some kind of reference to a class).

When you deserialize, java serialization machanism will look for this clas in your classpath.

To transmit over network, with java, you will use [ObjectOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) with Network stream classes..

Read this also: [java serialization over network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707987/java-serialization-over-network)

Hope this helps!

Comment: so in nutshell only state of object i.e instance variables are written to file or output stream. correct? During deserialization this state is assigned to object of apecific class in classpath at server side? in case of file is it simple text file?

Comment: all variables are serialized, only the ones with `transient` keyword that dont get serialized. at serverside you need the same class (package and name) as in your client side. Serialization don't rely on your final output(network or text file) so this is not a problem..

Comment: let me summarize to avoid any confusion. Basically new object will be created at serverside with same values of instance variables lying  in persisted object. correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading Python pickle (Python's serialization) tutorials for the basic knowledge:

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Network transmission is a separate issue and can be dealt without serialization. Basically sending a serialized object or a file over TCP/IP connection does not differ.