# How to pass Vector of data and header for the JTable by using Client/Server application

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, network-programming, jtable

Hello Stackoverflow users.

I have a little or big problem that I'm facing.

I'm currently doing a University project and I trying to display data from the database in to the JTable one of the GUI's that I made; using Client/Server application.

My main task/aim is to make a Server application to query a Database,
get data from the Database, store it in Vector or in any other format, pass it to the Client which will pass it to GUI's table and then display all the information.

I found a interesting example for storing all the data and headers in the Vector but that example is only appropriate for one class calling another class; link: http://chang.advits.com/populate-data-from-database-into-jtable-in-netbeans

So now I seeking for any advice and help that I can get. Thank you.

P.S. I don't know what code you like to see, so I will happily to post it, if needed.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: My advice is to do one thing at a time.  And, as soon as something works, don't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way. What gets sent over network is not Vectors, it's bytes at the end of the day. What you need is a way to convert your objects (or whatever) into bytes and back into objects.

One way to do it is Java serialization. That works if both sides are in Java, and is easier if they both can be updated at the same time (university projects fall under this). Check [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707987/java-serialization-over-network) out.

Another way is to do your own serialization. Suppose you convert your objects into strings: one object becomes one comma-separated line. Think CSV. Then on the server, you go through all your objects and call `toString()` on them; construct a string, send over a network. On the client, you read from the network using say `BufferedInputReader` so you can read one object at a time, and call `MyObject.parse(line)`.